# What does a Sharepoint engineer develop?

Tags: sharepoint

I'm new to Sharepoint but I do have a background in .NET development. How is it different to develop in Sharepoint? What does a Sharepoint engineers program exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a wide range of things a developer can do on SharePoint. A short list of most common (to me) items are:

- Web Parts
- Application Pages
- Event Receivers
- Workflow
- Timer Jobs

If you're not familiar with the raw ASP.NET Web Parts, SharePoint Web Parts are kind of analogous to ASP.NET User Controls with some additional wrapping that lets them store and retrieve settings, be targeted for visibility for users, etc. These are generally the most common (that I've seen) project for SharePoint. You can put multiple Web Parts on a page and the user can drag them to different zones to customize the way the page looks.

Application Pages are a bit more complicated. They require you to include a number of SharePoint-specific page directives and Content Areas in order for them to be rendered correctly. The result of which is the ability to control (the whole?) page render in SharePoint. This is in contract to Web Parts which only take up a small amount of space shared with other web parts on a web part page.

Event Receivers (List or Item receivers) are a lightweight mechanism to attach either to specific list instances or to whole list types. (A list is an instance of a type. There are pre-defined ones and a generic list type and you can use content type ids to specify your own unique list types.) Most commonly these are used when a new List Item is created/edited/deleted in a list to provide some additional notification, categorization, kick off some external process, etc. They're really easy to define and set up and one of the most flexible ways to listen for changes.

SharePoint Workflows are less common than the previous two, from my experience, but are still used quite heavily by larger organizations. Workflows can be synchronous (ItemUpdating) which will execute on the server currently serving the user, or asynchronous (ItemUpdated) which can be handled by any server in the SharePoint Farm when the Timer Service picks up the job. Workflows are generally used for watching forms, creating tasks, organizing new items, etc.

Timer Jobs are content-less pieces of code that are run on a schedule by the SharePoint Time Server. They run under the OWSTIMER (versus the w3wp IIS worker process) and there are some limitations and "gotchas" with these. They're analogous to Windows Scheduled Jobs.

Edit: Added Workflow information.

Edit 2: Added Event Receivers. Sorry! It's been awhile since I've had to crack my knuckles over SharePoint. This trip down memory lane is...a trip.